# In C++, how do I fix a pointer class's variable becoming a nullptr when I call it?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, forward-declaration

I want to use a class: class2, within a class: class1. From what I read, to prevent a circular dependency, one must forward declare class2 in class1.h and have it be a pointer. After calling a function from class2 in my class1.cpp file. I'm unable to call the variables within class2 without getting "Unable to read memory" or a nullptr.

Here's my code, thank you for the help:

//main.cpp

```
#include "Login.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Login login;

    login.StartMenu();
    cout << "ENDING" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

//Login.h (Class1)

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class GameManager;

class Login {
public:
    void StartMenu();
    

private:
    GameManager* manager;

};
```

//Login.cpp

```
#include "Login.h"
#include "GameManager.h"

void Login::StartMenu() {
    manager->GameStart();

}
```

//GameManager.h (Class2)

```
#pragma once

class GameManager {
public:
    void GameStart();
    
private:
    int level = 1;

};
```

//GameManager.cpp

```
#include "Login.h"
#include "GameManager.h"

void GameManager::GameStart() {
    cout << level;

}
```

Comment: You are not initializing `manager` inside `Login`.

Comment: Where do you initialise `manager`?

Comment: `to prevent a circular dependency` Which circular dependency are you talking about? `GameManager` doesn't use `Login`.

Comment: Also, you have weird includes of "GameManager.h" and "Login.h" at various places, only include the header where it is being used.

Comment: Also, you have a weird design. Ideally a GameManager should have a Login inside of it.

Comment: How would I initialize manager inside Login.h? It's of class type GameManager so I'm unsure what to equate it too. Also, do I put both .h files in all of the .cpp files except for main which should only have Login.h? Cause I'm unsure what you mean by weird includes at various places @kiner_shah

Comment: Are you aware of constructors?

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of them @Yunnosch

Comment: Introduce them in your [mre] as a foundation to help you with initialising. Then ask yourself "Which GameManager  instance do I want my Login instance to refer/point to?" You probably will have to create one beforehand and use it for/with/in the constructor; probably by giving it as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: So I took out the majority of the code and left the bare minimum to reproduce my problem but essentially I got several classes that call into one another but everytime I include the .h file of one class into another, I get a bunch of errors like syntax, missing specifiers, etc. @tkausl

Comment: Show that code and quote the error messages. Consider to first do everything in a single file and split later. "Everything" of the simplified [mre] of course. That single file MRE would be also very appreciated for this question.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm misunderstanding. If I put all the classes into one file and provide that single file MRE, wouldn't that eliminate my problem cause ultimately I'd like my int level to print so couldn't I just initialize it in main and output it? Also, by "show that code and quote the error message," do you want me to show the entire code for the current .h files and .cpp files? @Yunnosch

Comment: As I wrote '"Everything" of the simplified minimal reproducible example of course.' Which means all of the current files which is necessary to minimally demonstrate the problem you want to discuss. Which means, no, practically nothing of your current, probably huge, set of large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is a good idea to keep dependencies between headers to a minimum, and using pointers for classes that are only forward-declared is an established way to do that. This is good practice even if there are no circular dependencies because it can greatly reduce recompilation times in large projects.

Regarding your specific question: Essentially, the `Login` class, and especially the `Login::StartMenu` function,  needs to know which `GameManager`  instance to use. A pointer to that instance will be stored in `manager`. Ideally you can tell that at construction time of a `Login` instance via a `GameManager *` constructor argument:

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

class GameManager;

/// This class handles the login procedure for a specific
/// game manager which must be provided to the constructor.
/// It cannot be copied (so it cannot be 
/// in arrays) or default-constructed. 
class Login {
public:
    /// The constructor does nothing except initializing manager.
    /// @param gmPtr is a pointer to the game manager
    /// this instance is using.
    void Login(GameManager *gmPtr)
               : manager(gmPtr) { /* empty */ }
    void StartMenu();
private:
    GameManager* manager;
};
#endif // LOGIN_H
```

For completeness, here is how you would use it:

```
#include "Login.h"
#include "GameManager.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    GameManager gm;
    Login login(&gm); // <-- provide game manager to login

    login.StartMenu();
    cout << "ENDING" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If that is not possible because the `GameManager` instance does not exist yet or is otherwise unknown during construction of a `Login` instance (for example, if you have an array of `Login` instances, whose elements must be default-constructed) you can provide the argument to the `Login::StartMenu` method. But the constructor argument is much preferred because you can then be sure that the class is functional in the rest of the code — this kind of "invariants" are the main reason why constructors exist.

It is certainly possible that you don't need to hold a pointer at all, if all functions get that pointer argument. Whether the `Login` class has a one-to-one relationship with a `GameManager` (in which case it simply holds a pointer to it) or not (in which case every function is told each time) is a design decision.

Comment: What would the constructor look like to let the Login class know which GameManager to use and would that constructor be in the private part of Login.h or public of GameManager.h?

Comment: @IStrayDogI I included a header with an inline implementation of the constructor.

Comment: It works! I'm able to implement my other classes within one another. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IStrayDogI My pleasure. Good luck.

Comment: A caveat: Now you have to worry about ownership and object lifetime: If a GameManager whose address is kept in a Login class is used after it has been destroyed your program crashes. You could use smart pointers to avoid that, but for a start this is OK.

Comment: I have another question. It's the same code but I used your solution and now I'm having trouble calling a variable into other classes. It would mean a lot if you can check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087073/in-c-how-do-i-use-the-values-of-a-variable-from-one-class-to-another